# Is there a way to replicate an IDE's console like Eclipse, or NetBean's on a website?

Tags: java, jquery, html, jakarta-ee, netbeans-8

I've created a website portfolio and I want to show some of the projects I've done. But so far the many of the projects I've done have been in java, or C/C++ and the interactive/fun programs take input from the console.

I was wondering if there was a way to simulate those program using JavaServer Faces and taking input from a textbox (possibly) to be used in the java program I've created and posted back to the website.

Just to give you an idea of the kinds of programs I'd like to show. They range from simple things like determining if the entered data from the user is a leap year to a text I/O credit card validation program I've made up.

If my question is clear enough, does anyone have any ideas about how I can show the programs I've created?

I thought of creating a java class that writes the output data from the java file in a String and then posts that to the webpage, but then the user would have to frequently refresh the page. So I thought if I could somehow simulate the console on the website that would take care of that problem.

Extra: Is there any easy way to display javafx programs on a website?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: Taking data from the user and re-posting the output back to the website.

Comment: you could maybe create a ui for it with an input & output and use something like java web start to run it on a web page?

Comment: Thats a good idea! I just found System.setOut(PrintStream obj) which redirects the console output to a file. So maybe I can still create that UI and use the textbox and submit button for the input and Some kind of reader program to read the output text file from the program. Thanks for sharing your suggestion @TomFirth